# Sizing wide flange I-Beam for 20" span

Tags: code-compliance, structural, beam, engineering, building

I am doing a barn renovation project (pacific NW, 98922), and need to take out a large load bearing wall and replace it with a beam.  Was going to use an LVL (which I sized at about 5.5 x 18") but a lot of folks have recommended steel beams.  I am having trouble finding a good sizing chart for these beasts.  I am going to try to explain this as best I can.

Framing:  2x6 16" OC
Floor joists:  12" I-Joists 16" OC
Span:  20'

The tributary area is interesting, as there is a small second story over one half of it, and just a roof over the other half (of the tributary).  It is basically the exterior wall of the 2-story structure, with a large covered patio on the outside, if that makes sense.

So, trib #1 is 6':  This has second story above it (office space), with 6' of roof.  So 120 sq ft of floor and 120 sq ft of roof.

Trib #2 is also 6':  8' of roof.  No second story.  160 sq ft of roof.

Snow Load:  50

When I did the calculations, the beam needs to hold up about 1200 plf over that span without intermediate supports.

Basic calcs online say just divide the span in half ... so a 10" beam?  how wide?  I see 4" is generally standard for residential...

I should also note, the ends of the beam will be supported by wood posts onto existing perimeter footings.

I know, I should hire an engineer, but I feel I can do this safely with a bit of ground work and research.

Thanks!

Comment: Hire the engineer, they know the standards to work to and will take account of all conditions, also their work will be accepted by the televant authorities and insurance.

Comment: Yes, you should hire a qualified and licensed engineer to perform the proper analysis and give you a stamped copy of the design.  That will allow you to get a building permit and, most importantly, will get you a safe building.